# Personal Item On Spirit Airlines

Tags: air-travel, luggage, spirit-airlines

Is a laptop bag considered a personal item on Spirit Airlines?  I know I can bring a small backpack but was not clear what a personal item represented.

Comment: Have you asked them ?

Comment: On all the US airlines I know, the working definition of "personal item" is "anything that fits under a seat", so your laptop bag should be good unless it is unusually large.  But I've never traveled on Spirit.

Comment: @NateEldredge Spirit follows the nickel-and-dime business model.  If there are any US airlines that enforce weight or size limits strictly, you can bet that Spirit will be among them.

Answer (score 5):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Amq93qPLPPY) shows the sizer which apparently says a personal item is 16" x 14" x 12". Here's the relevant portion of a frame:

[image: Spirit personal item]

I also found it on the [Spirit site](https://customersupport.spirit.com/hc/en-us/articles/202096476-What-are-the-size-and-weight-limits-for-bags-) and it'll change to 18" x 14" x 8" for Travel April 4, 2017 and beyond. This is free and the "normal" carry on, max size 22" x 18" x 10" is paid.

Answer (score 1):

If you carry *both* a "small backpack" and a "laptop bag", the gate staff is supposed to count that as TWO items and the larger will be considered a Carry-On even if it also fits in the Personal Item sizer.

However, if the Laptop bag fits in the backpack, and the backpack then fits in the "Personal Item" sizer, you're good.  You can take the laptop bag out once the flight departs.